# How to make JavaScript exit the loop if the code sticks at an API call and it just hangs there forever?

Tags: javascript

How to make JavaScript exit the loop (time based) if the code sticks at an API call and it just hangs there forever?

Pseudo code:

for loop

--- api call

--- if got response from "api call" in 5 seconds, break for loop

Please be kind and answer the question. If it's not relevant please just skip this question.

Comment: you can use setTimeout function

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Afzal K.
>> never thought I use setTimeout to tackle this issue, but yes it does makes sense.

Srushti Shah
>> there is already a pseudo code please read & understand it, as it is sufficient enough to potray the problem.

Comment: come to think of it, actually what i want is the reverse of setTimeout. run the code and if for 5 seconds it doesnt return anything, abort.

Comment: There's no code in your question, so it's not clear if this "API call" is a synchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, we can use Promise and setTimeout.

First, we need to make the Promise by wrapping the API call with it. This will tell the code to wait for the response and continue when it's ready, or stop if there's a problem or it takes too long.

```
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  const promise = makeAPICall();
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error('Response took too long'));
  }, 5000);
    
  promise.then((response) => {

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    break;
  }).catch((error) => {

    clearTimeout(timeout);

  });
}
```

This way, if the API call takes longer than 5 seconds, the promise will be rejected, the timeout will be cleared, and the for loop will continue to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution

code runs every 2 seconds and after 10 seconds it stops

```
  function example(){
    var thisinterval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("testing")
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(thisinterval)
        }, 10*1000);
    }, 2*1000);
}
```